# bash 4.3.42 .: is /dev/fd/1 incorrect after redirecting or closing stdout?

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, proc

I redirect (or close) stdout but /dev/fd (and /proc/self/fd) still shows stdout going to the tty:

% exec 1>log
% ls -l /dev/fd/ >/dev/stderr

and get this

total 0
lrwx------ 1 guest guest 64 Sep 22 15:31 0 -> /dev/pts/1
l-wx------ 1 guest guest 64 Sep 22 15:31 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 guest guest 64 Sep 22 15:31 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 guest guest 64 Sep 22 15:31 3 -> /proc/14374/fd/

(ls -l /proc/self/fd/ prints the same).

The command
% date
does not print date on screen but

% cat log > /dev/stderr
Tue Sep 22 15:59:48 PDT 2015

shows that the output of date command has been written to 'log'

I can close fd 1 in a c program (or via exec 1>&- ) and /dev/fd/1 still shows it pointing to my tty.  Anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Fedora fc22 4.1.6-201 & Archlinux version??? on my Raspberry PI

Answer (score 0):

You closed file descriptor 1 of the shell, as you expected. However, when you checked to see what file descriptor 1 was, you used:

```
ls /dev/fd > /dev/stderr
```

But what’s that `>` do? For that single command, it reopens file descriptor 1, pointing to the file `/dev/stderr`. Hence, since `/dev/stderr` pointed to your pseudoterminal, `ls`’s file descriptor 1 will also point to your pseudoterminal, and `/dev/fd` reflects that. If you wanted to print out the file descriptors of the shell’s process, rather than `ls`’s process, you’d need to specifically say that:

```
ls -l /proc/$$/fd > /dev/stderr
```